# UITableView - contentOffset glitch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm running into problems with UITableView's `contentOffset` property. To illustrate the problem, I have subclassed `UITableView` and log all changes. Here's an example:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, 0} ({0, 97})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, 0} ({0, 0})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, 97} animated:NO ({0, 0})      <--
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, 97} ({0, 0})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, 0} animated:YES ({0, 97})     <--
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -1} ({0, -0})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -3.5} ({0, -1})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -7} ({0, -3.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -12} ({0, -7})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -18.5} ({0, -12})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -26.5} ({0, -18.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -33.5} ({0, -26.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -41.5} ({0, -33.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -49.5} ({0, -41.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -58.5} ({0, -49.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -66.5} ({0, -58.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -74} ({0, -66.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -81} ({0, -74})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -87} ({0, -81})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -91.5} ({0, -87})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -94.5} ({0, -91.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -96.5} ({0, -94.5})
- (void)setContentOffset:{0, -97} ({0, -96.5})
FINAL contentOffset = {0, -97}
```

I have marked the calls I make with arrows. The values in parentheses are the current values, the values behind the colons are the values to be set.

Now, as you can see the table view should set the content offset from `{0, 97}` to `{0, 0}` but it actually sets the content offset from `{0, 0}` to `{0, -97}`. What is going on?!

Comment: This may sound silly, but is there any particular reason you're using content offset (from the scroll view superclass) rather than the table view's `scrollToRow` methods?

Comment: @lxt: Yes, my rows can be quite high, so I want to scroll to specific positions inside a given row, not just to the top.